kaltura/nginx-vod-module access to remote to json manifest file in s3
I have JSON manifest in store in s3 and want to access it using vod_upstream_location, but it is always error 502 bad request. It is working fine with local json by alias /etc/nginx/json/
*noted s3 is not public but I sign it using lua script
below is my nginx:
open_file_cache          max=1000 inactive=5m;
    open_file_cache_valid    2m;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
    open_file_cache_errors   on;
    vod_mode mapped;
    vod_metadata_cache metadata_cache 256m;
    vod_response_cache response_cache 256m;

    location /s3/ {
            internal;
            # access_by_lua_file /usr/local/nginx/conf/sign.lua;
            proxy_pass ${PROXY_S3_END_POINT};
    }
    location /json/ {
            internal;
            # access_by_lua_file /usr/local/nginx/conf/sign.lua;
            proxy_pass ${PROXY_S3_JSON_END_POINT};
    }

    location /hls/ {
            vod hls;
            access_by_lua_file /usr/local/nginx/conf/sign.lua;
            vod_remote_upstream_location /s3;
            vod_upstream_location /json;
            # alias /etc/nginx/json/;
            gzip on;
            gzip_types application/x-mpegURL;

            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    }

